# xbindkeys does not work with bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I wrote a simple script in bash for light up the Fn led when CapsLock is pressed since the caps button on my t450 doesn't have its own led. 
So, I have to execute this script at the press of the key, for this reason I am trying to use `xbindkeys`.
In my `.xbindkeysrc` file I initially wrote:

`# Fn led button as Capslock led
 "sleep 0.1 && sudo bash ~/.scipts/Caps_to_Fn_led.sh"
 Caps_Lock`

Where `Caps_to_Fn_led.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
state=$(xset -q | grep Caps | cut -c20-24)

if [ $state = "off" ]
then
    modprobe -r ec_sys
    modprobe ec_sys write_support=1
    echo -n -e "\x06" | sudo dd of="/sys/kernel/debug/ec/ec0/io" bs=1 seek=12 count=1 conv=notrunc 2> /dev/null
    modprobe -r ec_sys
else
    modprobe -r ec_sys
    modprobe ec_sys write_support=1
    echo -n -e "\x86" | sudo dd of="/sys/kernel/debug/ec/ec0/io" bs=1 seek=12 count=1 conv=notrunc 2> /dev/null
    modprobe -r ec_sys
fi
```

`

It works if I use other buttons (Esc, Return), but not with Caps_Loks. 
It is also strange that `xbindkeys -k` does nothing when I press Capslock, so maybe the problem starts here..
I tried other names like `0x42`, `lock`, 0xffe5 from `xmodmap`, but nothing. How can I solve?

Comment: I dont use xbindkeys, but the man says you might need to add `keystate_capslock = enable` to the start of the config.

Comment: @meuh thanks for the reply. I put that line, but nothing changed. Even `xbindkeys -k` still doen't work

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason of why `xbindkeys` didn't not recognise the `CapsLock` key. Thre reason is that I had this line on my `i3 config`: `bindsym --release Caps_Lock exec --no-startup-id <command>` that didn't allow  `xbindkey` to work properly. I got it after that `xbindkeys -n` showed me:

`*** Warning *** Please verify that there is not another program running
which captures one of the keys captured by xbindkeys. It seems that there
is a conflict, and xbindkeys can't grab all the keys defined in its
configuration file.`

So after some research I finally found the i3 line.

Now the key is captured.